# bubble sort recursively without loops

Tags: c, recursion, bubble-sort

is it even possible to do bubble sort without any global/static variables, only one array and without a loops? I am wondering is it possible and if so, is it hard?

my function would only take array with numbers and size of it.

`int bubble_sort_asc_rec(int tab[], int size)`

Comment: Any iterative computation can be restructured as a recursive one, and vice versa.

Comment: Even with those restrictions?

Comment: Bubble sort does not require global variables in the first place, and iterative-to-recursive conversion does not require adding any.  Loops are the iteration being converted.  I don't see why there would be any need to add arrays other than the one being sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bubble_sort_pass(int array[], int size)
{
    /* We return the number of swaps in this iteration. */
    int swaps = 0;

    /* If the array contains 0 or 1 elements, it is already sorted. */
    if (size < 2) {
        return swaps;
    }

    /* Array contains at least 2 elements. */
    if (array[0] > array[1]) {
        /* First two elements are in wrong order. We need to swap them. */
        printf("Swap value %d with value %d\n", array[0], array[1]);
        int temp = array[0];
        array[0] = array[1];
        array[1] = temp;
        swaps += 1;
    }

    /* Recursively bubble sort the array starting at the 2nd element. */
    swaps += bubble_sort_pass(array + 1, size - 1);
    return swaps;
}

void bubble_sort(int array[], int size)
{
    /* Do one pass of bubble sorting the entire array. */
    printf("Start a bubble sort pass.\n");
    int swaps = bubble_sort_pass(array, size);

    /* If there was at least one swap, we have to do another pass. */
    if (swaps >= 1) {
        bubble_sort(array, size);
    }

}


int main()
{
    int numbers[] = {10, 8, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 9};
    int count = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
    bubble_sort(numbers, count);
    for(int i=0; i<count; ++i) {
        printf("numbers[%d] = %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In C you would not normally implement bubble sort this way; instead you would use an iterative approach (i.e. loops).

This recursive implementation is strictly for instructional purposes. Some so-called "pure functional" languages do not have any loops, they only have recursion. One such language is Erlang.

Note that the recursive call to bubble_sort is the last statement in bubble_sort. This is called "tail recursion" and it allows the compiler to optimize out pushing a return address on the stack. The C compiler (likely) will not make such a tail recursion optimization, but a functional compiler (e.g. an Erlang compiler) will.

The recursive call to bubble_sort_pass in bubble_sort_pass is currently not a tail recursion call, but it could easily be changed into a tail recursion call (verify this for yourself!)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using Python. However, instead of the function having the length of the array as the second argument, it has a count variable. I also included two test cases.

```
def get_largest(arr, count):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    if arr[0] >= arr[1]:
        temp = arr[0]
        arr[0] = arr[1]
        arr[1] = temp
        return get_largest(arr, count)
    else:
        return [arr[0]] + get_largest(arr[1:], count)

def bubblesort(arr, count):
    if count == len(arr):
        return arr
    arr = get_largest(arr, count)
    return bubblesort(arr, count + 1)

arr_test = [item for item in reversed(range(1,10))]
arr_test2 = [3, 5, 1, 7, 8, 9, 4]

print('First Test Array: ', arr_test)
print('Sorted: ', bubblesort(arr_test, 0))

print('Second Test Array: ', arr_test2)
print('Sorted: ', bubblesort(arr_test2, 0))
```

Comment: Can you explain this line: `return [arr[0]] + get_largest(arr[1:], count)` ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a version in java. Essentially is using loops because of the 'count' variable but still works fine.

```
public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] arr, int i, int count){
      
      
      if(count == arr.length){
         return arr;
      }
      
      if(i == arr.length - 1){
         i = 0;
         return bubbleSort(arr, i, count + 1);
      }
      
      if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1]){
         int temp;
         temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
         arr[i + 1] = temp;
         return bubbleSort(arr, i + 1, count);
      }
      
      bubbleSort(arr, i + 1, count);
      return arr;
      
   }
```

Comment: The answer is for C specifically, as shown by the tag. You should change your code to reflect that